# cannot get activity indicator to stop after asynchronous web request

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I need the activity indicator to start whenever a web request is made and stop once it has finished. Right now the indicator will display but the `.stopAnimation` is executing even right away and not waiting for the web request to finish.

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: 
UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var locationPickerOutlet: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var theProgressOutlet: UIActivityIndicatorView!

var locationspickerData: [String] = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    populateLocations()

}


func populateLocations() {

    self.locationspickerData = ["All Locations"]
    let url:URL = URL(string: "http://<web address>")!
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    //request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {
            return
        }

        let json: Any?
        do
        {
            json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
        }
        catch
        {
            return
        }
        guard let data_list = json as? NSArray else
        {
            return
        }
        if let locations_list = json as? NSArray
        {

            for i in 0 ..< data_list.count
            {
                if let locations_obj = locations_list[i] as? NSDictionary
                {
                    if let location_name = locations_obj["name"] as? String
                    {
                        self.locationspickerData.append(location_name)
                    }
                }
            }


            self.locationPickerOutlet.delegate = self
            self.locationPickerOutlet.dataSource = self
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
                self.theProgressOutlet.stopAnimating()
            }

        }

    })

    task.resume()

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return locationspickerData.count
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return locationspickerData[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let titleData = locationspickerData[row]
    let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 15.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blue])
    return myTitle
}
```

Comment: Maybe your web request is that fast ;-). Btw: Consider that the indicator won't stop in case of an error. That would be a good example for the `defer` statement.

Comment: PS: ...and the usual advice: Do not use any `NSMutable...` if there is a native Swift counterpart and not `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` in Swift either.

Comment: what alternative is there for NSDictionary?

Comment: Swift `Dictionary` (`[String:Any]`)

Comment: also, I feel like the web request is slower than it should be. It takes 30-40 seconds to load just 13 rows with one column.... any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the code self.theProgressOutlet.stopAnimating() after the DispatchQueue. Try this

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
//Your code    
            }
self.theProgressOutlet.stopAnimating()
```

try this and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the code that starts your UIActivityIndicatior. Just instantiate UIActivityIndicator in your viewDidLoad and call theProgressOutlet.startAnimating() before task.resume().

Remember that this solves the problem for your current code. Situations happen that you have multiple async requests in one scene and activityIndicator needs to start at the beginning of the process and end after all calls have finished successfully. To handle your current situation and the one I mentioned, I suggest you create a wrapper class with an internal Queue implemented. You can also create a http handler class to make all your requests from so you can handle this process at just one place and make later changes and debugging easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `hidesWhenStopped` property to `true` and start to animate the `theProgressOutlet` before resuming the `dataTask`.

```
theProgressOutlet.hidesWhenStopped = true
theProgressOutlet.startAnimating()

let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
    // YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
//Your code    
        }
 self.theProgressOutlet.stopAnimating()
```

nesting it in the above worked :)